# Blazor server side table with paging and multirow select feature using bootstrap?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a table which display records in a for each loop.Each row has a checkbox to show selected rows.

I want to keep track of the rows selected in the table so that when i navigate back to the pages where I had selected the rows I can see the checkbox checked.

My question.

1.Can I do this somehow without injecting javascript with bootstrap or some logic in the code behind?

If not what other logic can i use to bind the checkbox? (I was thinking keep a list of indices selected and check onrendering the rows but hope there is a nice way to do this)

2.How can I highlight  the selected rows when i check the corresponding row checkbox again without injecting javascript.

Comment: On further analyzing my requirement and Data I was able to achieve both the above conditions  through a collection of indices selected  and if conditions while building the UI

Comment: Hi, @Codegeek,  **Telerik** UI for Blazor Multiple Row Selection and Example of **Syncfusion** Blazor DataGrid Component all meet your needs but these are all not free.

Comment: Only using bootstrap to implement table with paging and multiple row selection is impossible mission. Bootstrap css describes how HTML elements are to be displayed. So it's hard to handle the interaction of a user with the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further analyzing my requirement and Data I was able to achieve both the above conditions through a collection of indices selected and if conditions while building the UI to render the checkboxes and the styling the rows